# Question on limits and trigonometry, $\cos(x)\cos(2x)\cdots\cos(nx)$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

How can i simplify the following product-
$$\cos (x) \cdot \cos (2x) \cdot  \cos (3x) \cdots  \cos (nx)$$
where $n$ tends to infinity and $x$ is a natural number?

All answers are appreciated, thanks for help .

Comment: sorry for the '/' its just cosx . cos2x . cos 3x .... cosnx

Comment: Hint: It's almost always $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a neighbourhood of the origin we have:
$$ \cos(x)\approx e^{-x^2/2}, \tag{1} $$
hence if we set $f_n(x)=\prod_{j=1}^{n}\cos(jx)$, we have that:
$$ \left| f_n(x)\right| \approx \exp\left(-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}\,x^2\right)\tag{2}$$
in a neighbourhood of the origin. Since $\left|\cos(j(x+\pi))\right|=\left|\cos(jx)\right|$, it follows that outside
$$ \pi\mathbb{Z}+\left(-\frac{\pi}{2n},\frac{\pi}{2n}\right) \tag{3}$$
$\left|f_n(x)\right|$ is bounded by $\exp\left(-\frac{\pi^2}{24} n\right)$ and:
$$ \forall x\not\in \pi\mathbb{Z},\quad \lim_{n\to +\infty} f_n(x)=\color{red}{0}.\tag{4}$$

Comment: thanks. it helped me solve my question.